# 2 DKMS drivers won't build correctly when installing new kernel after software update

Tags: dkms

I'm running 16.04. I have 6 DKMS drivers installed and running fine.

However, two communications device drivers (rtl88212au and rtl8814au) build incorrectly when the kernel gets updated during a Ubuntu software update. As such, these two drivers won't load. If I do a modinfo on either of these drivers after a Ubuntu software update, the *vermagic* value shows that it's for the previous version of the kernel, when it should show the current/new version of the kernel.

I do have secure boot disabled, and my other 4 DKMS drivers work fine. Just these two don't build correctly.

I have to do a `dkms remove`, and then these same drivers `dkms build` and `dkms install` just fine when done manually.

Here are the two dkms.conf files:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8812au"
PACKAGE_VERSION="4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="8812au"
MAKE[0]="'make' all"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"

PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8814au"
PACKAGE_VERSION="4.3.17.13720.20150622_beta_led"
MAKE[0]="'make' all"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="8814au"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"
REMAKE_INITRD="YES"
```

Any ideas on where to start looking for trouble?

Cheers, Al

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled in the BIOS. Otherwise, none of the unsigned DKMS drivers would load. I'm just having a problem with these 2 (out of 6) drivers building/installing correctly after a software update that contains a new kernel (when DKMS is used). Cheers, Al

Comment: What is the "new kernel"? What are error logs?

Comment: The "new kernel" is whatever Software Update decides to update to. The error can be seen if I try to manually load a bad driver using modprobe, and it errors with something like "format error" or "version error"... I forget the exact message. It's the reason that they don't load at boot time. Are you experienced in DKMS? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit these dkms.conf files:

for the rtl8812au...

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/dkms.conf
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/dkms.conf
```

for the rtl8814au...

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/src/rtl8814au-4.3.17.13720.20150622_beta_led/dkms.conf
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/4.3.17.13720.20150622_beta_led/build/dkms.conf
```

and replace:

```
MAKE="'make' all"
```

with this line:

```
MAKE[0]="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
```