# How do i get R8812au card to work

Tags: drivers, lubuntu

I purchased this wireless card off amazon [The card](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01M0Q51UI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

but for some reason even after going to Additional drivers and it finding the R8812au it worked once and then completely stopped  working(it does not seem to start for some reason)

ive also used the pre-included disk but this is the error i get:

```
 samuel@samuel-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo sh /media/samuel/REALTEK/linu
/install.sh
[sudo] password for samuel: 
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
/media/samuel/REALTEK/linux/install.sh: 17: cd: can't cd to driver
Decompress the driver source tar ball:

tar: Old option 'f' requires an argument.
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
/media/samuel/REALTEK/linux/install.sh: 38: [: unexpected operator
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
/media/samuel/REALTEK/linux/install.sh: 48: [: unexpected operator
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
samuel@samuel-System-Product-Name:~$
```

. What am i doing wrong? how do i get this up and running?

Comment: What version on lubuntu are we talking about?

Comment: 17.04 is the current version im running :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct driver - supposedly - is already in the repositories. No need to install that old script from Realtek (but it failed anyway so no harm done).

In Terminal,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Reboot.

Comment: There's a bug in this driver that won't allow dkms to rebuild this on a kernel update. See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/799108/2-dkms-drivers-wont-build-correctly-when-installing-new-kernel-after-software-u

Comment: Fixed but @heynnema those 3 other files to edit appart from the first one where just completely empty

Comment: @user153888 only the first two lines apply to the rtl8812au, and the version number for the first two lines might have changed, but you should have been able to find both locations. If the first edit went ok, then the second edit should have worked too. Open the paths in Nautilus file manager and see if there's just a small change to make those first two lines apply to your configuration. Please remember to vote for my answer if it was helpful.